# Can I attempt to get rid of my Cursed condition on the same reckoning phase that a Warlock inflicts me?

Tags: eldritch-horror

The warlock monster can inflict the closest investigator with Cursed during the Reckoning Phase. Since conditions are handled after monsters during the reckoning phase, can I then roll to see if I can get rid of the Cursed condition during that Mythos phase, or do I have to wait until the next Mythos phase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 10 of the [Rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/c7/d6/c7d6cff6-7025-41f9-8538-bb0626feb4f4/eh01_rulebook.pdf):

> Resolve these effects in the following order: Monsters, Ancient One sheet, *Ongoing* Mythos cards, and lastly investigator possessions and Conditions.

Would suggest that you can, however, in the [Reference Guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/EH01%20Reference%20Guide.pdf) it states:

> If a Monster is spawned or an investigator gains a component while investigators are resolving reckoning effects, they do not resolve the reckoning effect on that Monster or component.

Since cards are components, you cannot get rid of it on this turn.

Comment: Does this likewise mean that if I gain that Cursed condition, I do not have to act Cursed until after the Mythos Phase ends?

Comment: An interesting thought. My first instinct is that as soon as you become cursed it will affect you (as that is not a reckoning effect and therefore not affected by the rule above).

Comment: I noticed the reference guide portion you quoted was "they do not resolve the reckoning effect on that Monster or component", so that settles my question about ignoring being cursed for rolls during the mythos phase. I'll fix up your post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The problem was the rules use a symbol which didn't copy across correctly so I've been mentally filling in the gap.